# Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange. reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: cli

When am trying to authenticate via VS CODE integrated cmd pallets, I get below error

`Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange.reason: unable to get local issuer certificate`

However, when I use SFDX CLI I am able to authenticate, the strange thing is I can authenticate to many other orgs using same VSCODE but not able to authenticate that specific ORG/Instance.
. enabled API check box is checked.
Environment variable is set to `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED =0`

any help is much appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

there may be a chance of IP restriction. sometimes organizations whitelist the IP Space (CIDR) to avoid unauthorized access. I also suspect access controls is in place for certain instances/orgs. its to better to check with the salesforce system administrator once

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).